# Azure APIM VNET (Premium) usecases

Tags: azure-api-management

After evaluating APIM different tiers, Standard tier seems to be the most suitable one for the workload I am dealing with. I prefer to have a VNet (which is only supported in the Premium version) to isolate and create a proper boundary. But the premium tier is very expensive.

In my setup, my APIM will interact with  LogicApps, functions, and microservices deployed on docker in Azure. All these services sit in one VNet where external access is blocked. If I am not connecting to any on-prem service, do I need the VNet for my APIM? Most of the articles talk about premium version and VNet are connecting APIM with on-prem services.

Do we only need to have VNet for my APIM when we are connecting to on-prem services? What are the usecases when one must have APIM in a VNet? Any example would be really appreciated.

UPDATED:
there are a couple of objectives, only access APIs through APIM and use the express route to access on-prem APIs.

[image]

Comment: I got part of my question answered, I can restrict IP addresses on LogicApp https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/enterprise-integration/basic-enterprise-integration#security-considerations

I am still interested in the usecases where you would need VNet for APIM

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to put APIM into VNET is to make it able making a call to a service in that VNET or make it possible for a client to make a call to APIM, in both cases keeping traffic inside VNET. So it's really about why you want to keep your backend service or clients in VNET.

And isolating your backend APIs from everything but APIM is another scenario. Using VNET here is the strongest guarantee, but comes at a price. Another option is to have authorization (client certificates would work) between APIM and backend, but keep backend publicly available.

Comment: There are a couple of things I would like to achieve. Please see the updated portion in the original question. This is how the current setup looks like